How to set `org-show-context-detail` to show the heading, its items, but NOT any other headings?
When creating a sparse-tree, what I'd like to do is show all headlines matching the search query, and their entries, but no child or sibling headlines that don't match the query.
# Example document:
* H1 :mytag:
** H1.1 :mytag:
   Some text related to H1.1
** H1.2 :someothertag:
* H2 :someothertag:
** H2.1 :someothertag:

# When running sparse-tree search for "mytag" it should show:
* H1 :mytag:
** H1.1 :mytag:
   Some text related to H1.1

I would guess that such a basic operation has an existing command, but after looking for it for hours, it seems like it doesn't exist, and that I have to edit code in the org repository. I'm just trying to do a sanity check before I try to figure that all out.

Things I've tried
adjusting org-fold-show-context-detail
It seems that to adjust which items after a query are shown, we have to edit the org-fold-show-context-detail variable. The docs show that the following possibilities are available:
Allowed visibility spans are

  minimal        show current headline; if point is not on headline,
                 also show entry

  local          show current headline, entry and next headline

  ancestors      show current headline and its direct ancestors; if
                 point is not on headline, also show entry

  ancestors-full show current subtree and its direct ancestors

  lineage        show current headline, its direct ancestors and all
                 their children; if point is not on headline, also show
                 entry and first child

  tree           show current headline, its direct ancestors and all
                 their children; if point is not on headline, also show
                 entry and all children

  canonical      show current headline, its direct ancestors along with
                 their entries and children; if point is not located on
                 the headline, also show current entry and all children

The only reasonable options for me are minimal and local.

local: when I try local it indeed shows the entries (as I want), but also shows the next headline, as stated. I don't want the next headline to be shown.

minimal: when I try this, it correctly doesn't show the next headline, but now also no longer shows the entries. I don't really know what is meant by "if point is not on headline", since it also fails to show the entries when my cursor is at the top of the document before I do a sparse-tree query.


Using the org-ql package
When I use the org-ql package, and run a query using org-ql-sparse-tree, it simply does the same thing as org-sparse-tree, using the org-fold-show-context-detail variable that I've set.
Some related questions that didn't solve mine:

How do I get an expanded sparse tree?. This is the most closely related, but the recommendation is to use the local visibility span, which doesn't work as I said.

Hide siblings of first level on sparse-tree

Reveal entry's parents recursively but not siblings

Narrow to a sparse tree?



How do I get the desired behaviour? A sparse-tree that includes all headlines matching a query, together with their entries, but nothing else? It seems like such a simple command, there should be a default for it.

Am I going to have to adjust the org-mode code itself, and add a new entry-only visibility span? I hope there is a simpler way.

Is there a package that does this?

Or is there a way that I can pass a visibility span myself in lisp, without having to edit the org code itself?



